# Java-версии для учебы,какую выбрать?

Tags: java, version

Изучаю Java на последней 17 версии.
Тем не менее требования по джунам у работодателей следующие: знание 8 или 11 версии.
Получается,мне надо брать за основу для учебы 8 или 11 версию? Или все-таки лучше использовать возможности новейшей? Как этот вопрос решается в повседневной работе?

Comment: для обучения вам подойдет любая версия от 8 включительно. аргументация простая: в версии 8 произошли очень большие изменения, в т.ч. добавили функционалку, без понимания которой в настоящее время очень сложно, т.к. функционального кода написано огромное количество, да и большие фреймворки давно используют "плюшки" 8 версии. все, что выше, по большей части больше похоже на синтаксический сахар, посему разобравшись с версией 8 никаких проблем у вас не будет, остальное приложится само собой

Comment: То есть,лучше начать с 8 версии?

Comment: то есть это не имеет значения. подходит любая версия от 8 включительно и выше.

Comment: изучать надо последнюю версию

Comment: @Вячеслав имеет начать с 8 версии, потом изучить нововведения в новых версиях (глобально их не так уж много).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения изучения, всегда лучше изучать последнюю версию языка, так как актуальные знания - значительный плюс разработчику.

Касаемо повседневной работы, компании требуют знания более старых версий из-за множества уже существующих крупных решений, переписывать которые дорого, а поддерживать и дорабатывать нужно.

Объективно, когда навыки программиста не совсем нулевые, "деградировать" на пару версий назад труда не составит, поэтому и начинать с них не обязательно.

* Как минимум IDE подскажет, что такая конструкция не доступна в текущей версии и её нужно бы изменить на предлагаемую.